# Tailwind/React/Monorepo: The `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, nx-monorepo

I've apparently configured Tailwind correctly in my React project, which is on a Monorepo. However, I get this message as if I hadn't defined the content in tailwind.config.js yet, but I have.

```
warn - The `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty.
warn - Configure your content sources or your generated CSS will be missing styles.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
```

tailwind.config.js file:

```
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */ 
    module.exports = {  
        content: ['./src/**/*.{jsx, tsx}', 'public/index.html'],   
        theme: {
            extend: {},   
        },   
        plugins: [], 
    }
```

main.tsx:

```
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './main.css';

import App from './app/app';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

main.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

What else can I try?

Comment: The config file itself looks good. Since you said you are running this in a monorepo, can you tell me the the path of the config file (in relation to the repo root)? Which command were you running for the error to appear? Which folder you are running it from?

Comment: The Tailwind configuration file is in the first level of the React project, right when you open it. I used npx nx serve name-project to run the application. And I run it from the monorepo (global part of the monorepo project), I don't exactly enter the route of the project itself.

Comment: I suppose that all your projects have their own package.json. The tailwind config file needs to be in the same directory! If you want to share the config across multiple projects, create a tailwind config file in each project, import the base config file and export it again

Comment: There is only one package.json for the entire monorepo.